# trying to select checkboxes which have a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code where i am trying to select the images which only the specific class attached to it

```
$("#allimages").change(function () {
        $('input:checkbox:not("#checkAll")').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked',$(this).hasClass('isImage')));
    });
```

but it is selecting all checkboxes ignoring if any class is attached to it or not

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Cant see images

Comment: can't see images, i am not showing images, all i am doing is to select those checkboxes which has a class of isImage else do not select it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing the HTML, it's hard to know what you're trying to accomplish.

I would suggest the following based on what you have provided:

```
$("#allimages").change(function() {
  $("input[type='checkbox'].isImage:not('#checkAll')").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

When `#allimages` is changed, that same value will be sent to all checkboxes that have class `isImage` and is not `#checkAll`.